# Writing to BigQuery from Dataflow - JSON files are not deleted when a job finishes

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

One of our Dataflow jobs writes its output to BigQuery. My understanding of how this is implemented under-the-hood, is that Dataflow actually writes the results (sharded) in JSON format to GCS, and then kicks off a BigQuery load job to import that data.

However, we've noticed that some JSON files are not deleted after the job regardless of whether it succeeds or fails. There is no warning or suggestion in the error message that the files will not be deleted. When we noticed this, we had a look at our bucket and it had hundreds of large JSON files from failed jobs (mostly during development).

I would have thought that Dataflow should handle any cleanup, even if the job fails, and when it succeeds those files should definitely be deleted Leaving these files around after the job has finished incurs significant storage costs!

Is this a bug?

Example job id of a job that "succeeded" but left hundreds of large files in GCS: **2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is not by design.  Thank you for pointing this issue out to us.  We are looking in to it.

Comment: is there any update on this bug @Stephen Gildea?

Comment: This issue has been fixed.  Does it clean up for you now?

Comment: I'll test and let you know you

Comment: It still does not delete them, so it's not fixed yet.

Comment: Can you give us the job id of a run where this failed, please?

Comment: 2015-06-14_23_11_46-10500077558949649888 
2015-06-14_22_38_48-1428211312699949403
2015-06-14_21_20_54-457032749071301639 
2015-06-09_14_01_41-14283258936297888451 
2015-06-08_14_01_15-12768712141963235804 
2015-06-06_14_01_17-5368732127686623388
2015-06-05_14_01_40-9198178702237983816 
2015-06-04_14_01_39-13030365306324337282
2015-06-03_14_01_54-10043098466207071677 
2015-06-02_14_01_28-631058384198158831 
2015-06-01_14_01_27-451388638179897282 
2015-05-31_16_47_06-17545059535522628280 
2015-05-31_14_01_17-811014782842302431 
2015-05-30_14_01_24-14746237562774543211

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please also share with us the filepatterns of the files that remain?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing the file patterns to the original question.

Comment: Any update on this one?

Comment: It is fixed now, thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Sam McVeety. Hi Sam. It's still not fixed. Latest job id to fall victim: "2015-10-18_21_42_00-10464098091730714323". "Oct 19, 2015, 10:42:15 PM
S17: (c881a7449cc3e59): Unable to delete temporary files gs://cdf/binaries/dfp_denormailization/10464098091730713414/dax-tmp-2015-10-18_21_42_00-10464098091730714323-S17-1-807aff4e4339991/@DAX.json$"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is still happening we decided that we'll clean up ourselves after the pipeline has finished executing. We run the following command to delete everything that is not a JAR or ZIP:

```
gsutil ls -p <project_id> gs://<bucket> | grep -v '[zip|jar]$' | xargs -n 1 gsutil -m rm -r
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possible cause of left over files is cancelled jobs. Currently dataflow does not delete files from cancelled jobs. In other cases files should be cleaned up.

Also the error listed on the first post "Unable to delete temporary files" is the result of a logging issue on our side, and should be resolved within a week or two. Until then, feel free to ignore these errors as they do not indicate left over files.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug where the Dataflow service would sometimes fail to delete the temporary JSON files after a BigQuery import job completes. We have fixed the issue internally and rolled out a release with the fix.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Is that better?  Their specific question was whether this was a bug.

Comment: No this is not an answer. An answer would be an explanation of what fixed the bug. This is a comment.

Comment: This is not fixed. We had another job run, and the JSON files were not deleted afterward.

Comment: Looking into it.  Apologies.